# How to animate polyline points using doubleanimation / pointanimation

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes, kinect, polyline

Assuming I have a Polyline and I wish to move only the end of the Polyline from A to B using animation. How should I go about doing it?

p/s: I'll still prefer if the suggestion is for polyline and not for other controls such as path and so on :)

[image]

Comment: at the moment I am going to do with the transform property, but I'll still appreciate any suggestions on how to manipulate with points.

Comment: Do you use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.aspx RotationTransform?

Comment: @Tigran Yeah, I am currently using that, but I just realised I cannot use that. The start point is constantly moving. If I use rotate, it lacks that flexibility since the startpoint will be at a spot permenantly or until another event is invoked. (I am sorry for the bad explanation but this is the best I can convey myself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible out of the box as far as I'm aware, since you're trying to animate a `Point` within a `PointCollection`. What you really need is a `PointCollectionAnimation`, which WPF doesn't provide. However, the awesome Charles Petzold wrote [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163397.aspx) some time ago showing you how you can go about it.

Answer (score 0):

As the link mentioned in the accepted answer doesn't work anymore, so I am posting my approach.

```
<Path Stroke="Red">
            <Path.Data>
                <GeometryGroup>
                    <LineGeometry x:Name="G1" StartPoint="100,100" EndPoint="100,0"/>
                </GeometryGroup>
            </Path.Data>
            <Path.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>                            
                            <PointAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetName="G1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="EndPoint">
                                <PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                                    <PathGeometry Figures="M 100,0 C 150,50 200,75 250, 100" />
                                </PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                            </PointAnimationUsingPath>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Path.Triggers>
        </Path>
```